# Match key explanation

Tags: rules-engine

I am having a hard time to technically understand how matching keys work in the context of duplicate management.
Specifically.

1. what is the reason behind matching key generation.
2. How keys are generated and how they affect the matching process.

I have already had a look at the documentation but the process is still obscure to me.

Comment: Are you talking about Matching Rules, used as part of Duplicate Management? Please [edit] your question to provide additional context and detail.

Comment: Thank you I did it.

Answer (score 0):

[How Match Keys Are Generated and Used in Matching Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rules_match_key_process.htm&type=5).

> what is the reason behind matching key generation.

Searching millions of records in real-time would be incredibly slow. Imagine scanning your hard drive to find a single file that contains a single word. This could take minutes or hours, even with the latest in storage technology. To alleviate this problem, the system utilizes indexes, which can be navigated in mere milliseconds for millions of records. The keys are normalized so they can be easily compared, and then indexed for performance. This is what allows real-time matching of duplicates in Salesforce.

> How keys are generated and how they affect the matching process.

From the link above:

> 1. The matching equation that determines the arrangement of the fields is rewritten into a standardized format that translates the OR
>    statements into AND statements.
> 2. Values for fields in the matching rule are normalized.
> 3. A match key is generated using the field combinations specified in the standardized field format. A matching rule can have multiple match
>    keys. A custom matching rule can have up to 10 match keys; you’re
>    prevented from saving a matching rule that requires more.
> 4. The match key is used to combine normalized field values for each record.

They *are* the matching process. The system uses these keys to quickly identify potential duplicates without using full table scans, which could take minutes or even hours in the largest databases. This is also why enabling a Matching Rule takes time, as a full table sweep is required for initialization.

Records with the same Match Keys are flagged as duplicates, and those that do not are not. There are technical details not listed in the documentation, just know that it's basically creating "fingerprints" or "signatures" for each record and then comparing them to an index.

Comment: Hi. Thank you a lot for your reply. The point that is still confusing to me is this: The matching equation that determines the arrangement of the fields is rewritten into a standardized format that translates the OR statements into AND statements. ..... I don't see the reason why the OR statement should be translated into AND,

Comment: an issue that has occurred to me recently was that and EXACT matching rule was identifying a lot of duplicated that in fact where not there, So I have assumed that problem is related on how the matching keys for those specific records are generated. I would like to know your thoughts on this thank you again in advance.